# Sort Mapbox annotations

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, mapbox

I'm currently looking to sort all annotation using mapbox.

I know that I should use the following process :

```
//implementing this method and do the sort here   
(NSComparator)annotationSortingComparatorForMapView:(RMMapView *)mapView

// remove current annotation and use the sorted array to redraw them
[mapView removeAnnotations:[mapView annotations]];
[mapView addAnnotations:annotationSorted];
```

The issue here is that I'm lost about where I should call this process.

I'm actually using `mapView:layerForAnnotation:` to return the shapes that should be draw but if I'm not wrong, it's a callback so not really invoked from the code.

Thanks for your help.

### EDIT:

Thanks to jszumski I figured out a implementation. For those who need it in the futur there it is :

```
- (NSComparator)annotationSortingComparatorForMapView:(RMMapView *)RmapView
{
    NSComparator sort =^(RMAnnotation *annotation1, RMAnnotation *annotation2)
    {
        // Sort user location annotations above all.
        //
        if (   annotation1.isUserLocationAnnotation && ! annotation2.isUserLocationAnnotation)
            return NSOrderedDescending;

        if ( ! annotation1.isUserLocationAnnotation &&   annotation2.isUserLocationAnnotation)
            return NSOrderedAscending;

        // Amongst user location annotations, sort properly.
        //
        if (annotation1.isUserLocationAnnotation && annotation2.isUserLocationAnnotation)
        {
            // User dot on top.
            //
            if ([annotation1 isKindOfClass:[RMUserLocation class]])
                return NSOrderedDescending;

            if ([annotation2 isKindOfClass:[RMUserLocation class]])
                return NSOrderedAscending;

            // Halo above accuracy circle.
            //
            if ([annotation1.annotationType isEqualToString:kRMTrackingHaloAnnotationTypeName])
                return NSOrderedDescending;

            if ([annotation2.annotationType isEqualToString:kRMTrackingHaloAnnotationTypeName])
                return NSOrderedAscending;
        }


        return NSOrderedSame;
    };
    return sort;
}
```

Comment: You need to implement the sort in your delegate, the same way that `mapView:layerForAnnotation:` is implemented there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your comparator is correctly implemented, it should just work.  I don't believe you need to remove and re-add all the annotations unless you are explicitly changing the logic of the comparator each time.

From [the documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk/api/Protocols/RMMapViewDelegate.html#//api/name/annotationSortingComparatorForMapView:):

> The block will be called repeatedly during map change events to ensure annotation layers stay sorted in the desired order.

Comment: Yes, you're totally right, I figured this out a bit later yesterday. But your explanation comfort me in my solution. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide me any example of implementation of this block ? I have to compare Shapes and userlocation point. And can't really figure out how compare those 2 objects.